# define entry point in legacy Grunt/Angular app for babel-pollyfill

Tags: javascript, angular, gruntjs, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I'm working with a legacy app we are slowly dragging forward to more modern libraries, etc. (I say this in advance to try to head off any "just upgrade to webpack/yarn/etc" answers. We're working on it, incrementally.)

Issue summary:

I have successfully included "grunt-babel": "^7.0.0", (I can see it working fine with a test `let testBabel = 1` conversion). I also require "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"," to handle things like `.includes()` & Array function, which I have pulled in via my package.json "dependencies" (not "devDependencies", as I was instructed in the docs). My actual issue should be pretty simple: I have no understanding of the proper way to "load this via the entry file" for the set of libraries I am using.

Angular is v1.5

My Setup:

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-babel": "^7.0.0",
"grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
"grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.9.1",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
"grunt-shell": "^2.1.0",
"load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "d3-selection-multi": "~1.0.1",
    "node-bourbon": "^1.2.3"
  }
```

GruntFile.js

```
        src: [

            './app/vinoEZ/javascripts/__header/jquery/jquery_number.js',
            './app/vinoEZ/javascripts/__header/jquery/hottie.js',
            './bower_components/localforage/dist/localforage.js',
            './bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js',
            './app/vinoEZ/javascripts/__header/polyfill/entry.js',
            './app/vinoEZ/javascripts/__header/polyfill/eventsource.js',
            './bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js',
            './bower_components/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js',
            './app/vinoEZ/javascripts/__header/underscore/underscore.js',
            './app/vinoEZ/javascripts/__header/myapp/base.js',

        ],
        dest: './public/javascripts/myapp.head.min.js',
```

("myapp" is a substitute for our company name). The `pollyfill/eventsource.js` was existing, and so I have been working with `pollyfill/entry.js` as some of my experimentation - that may not be needed in the end.

In addition, we have our `app.js` file with all of our `angular.module` loading & directive stuff.

What I've tried:

I have tried adding `require("babel-polyfill");` as the first line inside my `module.exports = function(grunt) {` - that seems to be ignored & I've been told that's wrong anyway

I have tried adding `require("babel-polyfill");` and `import "babel-polyfill";` inside that entry.js, which obviously isn't going to work and doesn't (syntax error as javascript doesn't understand)

I have tried add the same to the top of the angular app.js file but that just blows up my angular.

Really looking for a "write these words here", solve it for me answer, as I'm pretty sure it is a dead simple thing if you know what to type, but I'm at a loss.

TIA!

Comment: (I'm not a front-end dev primarily; I may not have included something important in understanding my setup. If so, please comment & I'll get that up straight away )

Answer (score 0):

In the end, seems like a direct link is the easiest way to deal with this, especially as we are slowly upgrading the entire system.

CDN for anyone interested: https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/docs/